# Wygwam 2.7: How Can I Customize the Image Properties Modal?

Tags: wygwam

I would like to customize Wygwam's Image Properties modal to display the following options only:

- Upload image files from local HD
- Add Alt text
- Add a caption

I don't want site members to be able to:

- See existing images
- Resize images
- Style images
- Use other advanced options

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly, I'm not sure theres a way to do this. You can customize parts of CKEditor 3 (the WYSIWYG editor Wygwam uses) like the images or link dialog windows because they are each separate JS files. Just copy the file and start hacking away.

But the actual uploading of files is handled by either CKFinder (CKeditor's counterpart), the build-in EE file manager, or anther third-party alternative like Assets. And as far as I know, none of them allow you to only upload files or even just see files the current users has uploaded but none of the others.

There might be a way to use [DevDemon's Channel Images](http://www.devdemon.com/channel_images/) to accomplish this. It creates an upload directory for each entry and only uploads images there. So the user would only be allowed access to that entry's images.

Channel Images also has a Wygwam button that let's the user insert an image from Channel Images. It's pretty plain. You pick and image and it drop in an `<img>` tag. You should be able to hack it to create a `<figcaption>` for instance because it's built in JS like any other CKEditor button.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using the "Advisory Title" in Advanced properties. It makes a "title" attribute. Then using jQuery to render an html caption from the attribute of the image tag. It's OK, but the content requires that you code things like quotes, apostrophes etc. as htmlchars, like ' or " (instead of " and '); or it will ruin your markup.

When the image is placed in the copy when editing in Wygwam, right click on it, and you will see a menu item for image properties. Find "Advisory Title" and write your caption in there. Make sure there are no (" or ') characters. Wygwam will save the content. Then you can pull out the value using jQuery and create a caption directly beneath the image.

One thing to try would be to see if settings can be changed in the Wygwam channel to allow quotes and store them as html characters. A problem with this method is that it is probably not what the title attribute is for.